# Что вернул нам сервер

Tags: php, клиент, сервер, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть форма и обработчик
Когда я отправляю форму, вызывается следующая [функция](http://codepaste.ru/14707/), на сервере я проверяю введены ли данные, если нет, то возвращаем клиенту ошибку. Короче, не охота, да и не правильно было бы отправлять клиенту информацию перемешанную с HTML кодом, я подумал, можно ли как нибудь отдать с сервера клиенту допустим переменную $error, а на стороне клиента в JS проверить если сервер вернул переменную $error, то помещаем и выводим её:

```
<div class = 'alert alert-error'>$error</div>
```

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Отправляйте JSON вместо HTML, а на клиенте делайте eval полученной строки.

Comment: JSON [](hidden)

Answer (score 1):

да можно, отправляйте данные в json скажем таким образом:

```
$result= array('status'=>'error','message'=>'неправильно ввели пароль');
echo json_encode($result);
```

А уже на строне js приложения var result=JSON.parse(html);
У вас получится result->status и result->message; и делайте с ним все что угодно

Comment: учитывая, что автор использует ``jQuery.ajax()``, вместо ``JSON.parse()`` можно просто добавить еще один параметр ``dataType: 'json'``